# Order List of Arrays by the information in the arrays?

Tags: c#

What i want to do is reorder a list of arrays by the information that is in the arrays. For example my list might have 20 Long[] arrays that i want to order by Highest Totallaps and Lowest TotalTime Have tried several things though having trouble coming up with anything. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public List<long[]> Reorderedlist()
{
    _timeKeeper._timeKeeperControls controls = new _timeKeeper._timeKeeperControls();

    List<long[]> returnList = new List<long[]>();

    List<long[]> listToReOrder = new List<long[]>();

    listToReOrder = controls.teamInfoInClass("1",ContactlessTimer.Properties.Settings.Default.currentRaceID);

    //newlist contains list of long[] arrays
    //each array contains

    //long[0] = id1 (eg 33) 
    //long[1] = id2 (eg 34)
    //long[2] = totalLaps (eg 10)
    //long[3] = total time (eg 340000 in miliseconds)

    foreach (long[] Arr in listToReOrder)
    {
        foreach (long info in Arr)
        {
            //order
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ methods: `OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy`:

```
List<long[]> returnList = listToReOrder.OrderByDescending(x => x[2])
                                       .ThenBy(x => x[3])
                                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Heaps spent so much time yet the answer seems so simple. Could you please explain how it works e.g. why have you used the values 2 and 3?